# count how many files are in a folder

Tags: jquery

Is there a way using jquery to look in a folder and count how many say .jpg are in a folder?
I've looked around an have only found ajax being a solu.

I'm trying to return the amount of .jpg's are in a folder for a for loop I'm using

Comment: No, jQuery can't do that--it's simply a client-side JS framework. That logic has to be run server-side, since that's where those files live. AJAX is simply a way of having the client ask the server to give it information, so you can use jQuery to query the server, but the file counting logic will be run by the server

Comment: localhost or not, you still have to consider the server and client as two separate entities.  Just because the server is on the same machine doesn't mean your page has private access to what the server contains within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without querying the server for that information (e.g. via AJAX or some other http request), there is no way to know what files exist on the server.

However, if you consider that the webpage you see in the first place is a page that was given to you by the server, your server could include the full file listing already contained in a JavaScript array variable as the page is being requested and sent to the client.  Technically done during an http request, but it isn't something you have to AJAX.  The only drawback to this method is that if the file listing changes while you are on the page, the list you see doesn't get updated until the entire page is refreshed by the client (you will need AJAX for real time updates).

If your server is PHP, you would basically add `<?php ?>` tags to your page within the `<script>` element and echo a new variable with all the filenames appended to it.  Since it is now a variable in JavaScript, JQuery can now access it.  In other server languages you would do similar things.